# The text string you entered is too long excel error

Tags: excel

I have **12919** characters in my excel cell as per documentation MS Excel Allows Maximum 32,767 characters in a cell but i am still getting this error in excel while entering my text in a cell

> The text you entered is too long. Reduce the number of characters used or cancel the entry

This is my text that i am entering

```
-41, 01 The One, 360 Electrical, 3H Italia, 3M, 5.11 Tactical, 50 Cent, 5ive Star Gear, 88 Rue Du Rhone, A Line, A.N. Enterprises, A.S.N. Publishing, Abco Tech, Accessories, Accessory Power, Accutime Watch Corp, ACET Venture Partners LLC, Acorn, Adee Kaye, Adidas, Adrenaline Technologies LLC, Adrienne Vittadini, Advance, AFe Power, Agent X Watch, Agent-X Watch, AiWatch, AK Anne Klein, Akribos XXIV, Alba, Alchemy Of England, Alessi USA Inc, Alex And Ani, Alex Toys, Alexander Hi Tek, ALINE, Allen, Alpina Watches Int., American Coin Treasures, American Educational Products, AMT, And Watch, Animal, Anne Klein, ANNIN & COMPANY, AOYI WATCH, Apache, Apple, Aqua Freeze, Aqua Master, Aqua System, Aquacrown, AquaSunOzone, Aquaswiss, Arbutus, ArcticShield, Armand Nicolet, Armani, Armani Exchange, Armitron, Armour Lite, Armourlite, ARSENAL, Arts Education IDEAS, Ashworth, ASICS, Asprey, ASUS, Atlantic Safety Products, Audemars Piguet, AUGUST Steiner, Avalanche, Avio Milano, Axcent, AXESS, Azzaro, Badash, Badgley Mischka, Ball, Ballast Time Instruments, Balmain, Barbie, Baume & Mercier, BCBG, BCBG Max Azria, BCBGirls, Bedat, Bell & Ross, Bell And Ross, Bellagio Bel Tempo, Ben & Sons, Benzara, Berger M Z & Company, Bering, Bertha, Bertucci, Bertucci Watches, Best Desu, Betsey Johnson, Bewell, BIILII Profession Design, BJTEE, Black & Decker, Black Dice, Blaze Display, Bling Jewelry, Bluemono, BNF, Body Glove, Boker, BOLD, Bonanza International, Bond Mfg, BOSS AUDIO SYSTEMS, Boss Gloves, Boum Watches, BOWFLEX, Boxer Adhesives, Bradshaw Int'l., Brainydeal, Brands 88, BrassCraft Mfg Co., Braun, Breda, Breed Inc, Breil, Breil Milano, Breitling, Brera Orologi, Brita, Broan-NuTone LLC, Brondell, Brooklyn Watch Co., Brookstone, Builders Edge, Bulgari, Bulk Buys, Bull Titanium Watches, Bulova, Burberry, Burgi, Burgmeister, Burlingham London Ltd, BVLGARI, Cabochon, Calibre Watches, Calvin Klein, Calvin Klein CK, Calvin Klein Jeans, Camco, Cammenga, CampCo, Cannon, Caravelle By Bulova, Caravelle New York, Carlo Monti, Carolina Herrera, Carrera, Carson Optical, Cartier, Carucci Watches, CASIO, Casio Edifice, Casio G Shock, Caterpillar, Caterpillar Watches, Catherine Lillywhite, Catherine Maladrino, Catorex, Centorvm, Centric, Ceramic Filters (Doulton), Cerruti, Certina, Champion, Champion Sports, Chaney Instruments, Chapin, Chaps, Chard Products, Charles Hubert, Charles-Hubert, Charmex, CHARRIOL, Cheap Monday, Cheapo Brand, Chevrolet, Chicong Technology Co. LTD, Chineon, Chopard, Christian, Christian Audigier, Christian Dior, Christian Lacroix, Christian Van Sant, Chronotech, Citizen, Classic Concepts, Claude Bernard, Clyda, Coach, Colibri, Columbia, Commercial Water Distributing, Company X, Conair Corporation, CONCORD, Conqueror Watches, Control Brand, CONVERSE, Cool Techno, Corn Electronics, Corum, Corvette, Costa Del Mar, Crayo, Cronometro, Cross, Croton, Crown Master, CRYSTAL GROUP, CS Power, Cuervo Y Sobrinos, Culligan International Company, Custo Barcelona, Custom, Custom Leather Craft, Dakota, Dakota Watch Company, Dalas Watch, Daly Days Table Co. Ltd., Daniel Green, Daniel Wellington, Daniel Wellington Watches, Danish Design, Davidoff, Dayspring Cards, Despicable Me, Deuce Brand, Dexter Sinister, DFactory, Diadora, Diamond Princess, DIAMONDBACK, DICAPac, Diesel, Diesel Site, DIGIFLEX, Dimacci, Disney, DKNY, Doctor Who, Dolce & Gabbana, DollTV, Domeni Co, Dong Sheng Jewelry Co. Ltd, Dora The Explorer, DreamWorks, Dreyfuss & Co., Du Maurier Watches Ltd, Ducati, Dynamic, E-MENS Collection, E-pill Medication Reminders, EachBuyer, EARTH, Eastway International (HK) Limited, Ebel, EC2WORLD, ECbidbuy, Ed Hardy, EDGE Tech, EDOX, Edwin, EForCity, ELECSHELL, Electric, Electric California, Elini Barokas, Elle, Emporio Armani, Emtech La Costa Co, ENET Technology CO.LIMITED, English Laundry, Epoch, Epson America, Equipe, Equipe Tritium Watches, EQUITY, Esprit, ESQ, Eterna, ETopSell, Evergreen Enterprises Inc., Eviga, EWatch Factory, Extro Italy, EYKI WATCH, Faber, Feldo, Fendi, Fenghua Luoou LCD Bracket, Ferrari, Festina, Fiilex, FiiSmart, Fine T, FINIS, Fiorucci, Five Star Inc, Fiyta Sales Co.Ltd, Fjord Watches, Flexi, Floveme, FMD, Follie Follie, Forney, Forsining Watch Company Limited, Fortis, Fossil, Fox Outdoor, Foxnovo, Franck Muller, Frederique Constant, Freelook, Freestyle, French Connection, FRONTIER, Frontier Natural Products, Fruit Of The Loom, Fruitz, FUJIFILM, Fusion, G Shock By Casio, G-Shock, G-Unit, G.M.Five, Game Time, Game Time Shop, Gametime, Garmin, Gattinoni, GE Animation, Gearonic Inc, Gelo, Gemorie, General, General's, GENERIC, GENEVA, Geneva Platinum, GERNERIC, Gevril, Gift Connection Inc., Gill Sailing Gear, Gino Franco, Gio Monaco, Giorgio Armani, Giorgio Fedon, Girard Perregaux, Giulio Romano, Glam Rock, GlamFit Jewelry, Global Time International, Go-Jo Ind., Godinger, Gold And Diamond, Grand Master, GRAND VALUE, Grovana, Guangzhou Garment Co. Ltd., Gucci, Guess, Guy Laroche, GV2, H. Best Ltd., H3 Tactical, Hadley Roma, Hamilton, Harley Davidson, Harris Communications, Haurex, Haurex Italy, Hazard 4, Hello Kitty, Heritage, Heritor Watches, Hermes, Hip Hop Watches, HME Watch Company, Hollyta Technology Co.LTD., Home Revolution, Horizon, Hot Energy Limited, HOTARU, Hublot, Hugo Boss, Humvee, Hunting Made Easy, HUSH PUPPIES, HydrOlix, Hygeia, I By Invicta, I&I Sports, IBELI WATCH, IBoost, Ice, ICE-Watch, ICE.COM, Iceberg, Icetime, Icon Bijoux, If You Care, IHome, Immersion, Impacto, Impecca, InDigi-usa, Infantry Co., Infinity, Ingenuity, Ingersoll Watches, Ingersoll/Rand, InSinkErator, Intex Recreation, Invicta, Ionlyyou, Ironclad, IS, Isport, Ita, ITU CO.LTD., IVIEW, Iwatch Trend, IWC, Izod, J Springs, J's Exte, Jackson Safety, Jacques Farel, Jaeger Lecoultre, Janel Russell, JARAGAR Watch, Jasmine, JBW, Jean Paul Gaultier, JeanRichard, Jennifer Lopez, Jet Set, Jet Set Of Sweden, JETWAY, Jewelry Adviser, JGoodin, JinTaoRui, Jivago, JMT, Jo Jino, Joe Rodeo, Johan Eric, Jorg Gray, Joshua & Sons, Joshua And Sons, Joy, JP Commerce, Juicy Couture, Just Bling, Just Cavalli, Just Mobile, Just Watches USA, Juventus, Karl Lagerfeld, Katadyn, Kate Spade, Kenneth Cole, Kenneth Cole New York, Kenneth Cole REACTION, Kienzle, KIKAR, Kimberly-Clark Professional, KIMIO WATCH, King Master, Klokut, Komono, Kr3w, Kronen&Șhne, Kwik Tek Sportsstuff, LA MER, LaCie, Laco Watches, Lacoste, LaCrosse, Lambretta, Lancaster, Leadfar, LEGO, Leiyuan Industrial Co.Ltd., LG Electronics, Libbey Glass, Liberty, Lifetrak, LIGHTING TECHNOLOGIES INTERNATIONAL, Lincoln Digital, LIP Watch, Little Griddle, Liu Jo, Locman, Longines, LORUS, Lorus Seiko, Lotus, Louis Erard, Love2morrow, LRG, Lucien Piccard, Luminox, Luxurman, M, M2Coutlet, Madame Alexander, Maestro Luggage, Manzella Productions, MAPA Professional, Marc By Marc Jacobs, Marc Ecko, Marc Ecko Unltd, Marc Jacobs, Mark Maddox, Marvel, Marvel Comics, Maserati, Matashi, Matthew Williamson, Maui Jim, Maurice Lacroix, Max Toy Co., MCR Safety, Meccaniche Veloci, Mechanix Wear, MedCenter, Megadream, Meister, Melnor, Memorex, Memphis, Mental Beats, MEPHISTO, Meree Technology, MICGRAND, Michael Kors, Michael Lau, Michele, MICROFLEX, Mido, MILER WATCH, Milleret, Milus, Minicyber, MIO, Mistura, Mitaki-Japan, Mobi Technologies Inc., Modus, Momentum Books Llc, MOMO, Monaco, Monarch, Mondaine, Mondia, Montana Silversmiths, Montblanc, Montres De Luxe, MONTRES DE LUXE MILANO, MORELLATO, Morphic Watches, MOS Watches, Moschino, MOTA, Motorola, Movado, MSA SAFETY WORKS, Mulco, Mulco Watches, Murano, MyKronoz, MyPartyShirt, MYWISH, MZBerger & Company, Nary Watches, National Geographic, Nautica, Nava Watches, Navarre Corporation, NBA, NDS, Nebo, Neet Products Inc, Neewer, NEFF, Nemesis, Nemesis Watch Inc, Netspower, New Century, New Wave Enviro Products, Newgate Watches, Nice Italy, Nickelodeon, Nike, Nina Ricci, NINGBO FEIXIANG AUTOMOBILE PARTS FACTORY, Nivada, Nixon, Nooka, Noon Copenhagen, North Coast Medical, Not Specified, NYchi USA, O.d.m., Oakley, Obaku, OCEANAUT, ODM, OEM Industries, OEM Parts Supply, Ohsen Watches Co., Oliver Peoples, Omax, Omega, Omega Watches, OmniPure, Oneida, Oniss, Oregon Scientific, Orient, Original Penguin, Oris, ORKINA WATCH, OULM WATCH, Overstock, Oxbow, Oxygen Watches, PAlight, Panerai, Paris Hilton, Paris Jewelry, Parmigiani Fleurier, Pathfinder, Pavewel, PC USA Corporation, Pebble Technology Corp, Pentair, Pepe Jeans, Petra, Pfister, Philip B, Philip Stein, PHILIP WATCH, Philippe Starck, Philosophers Guild, Pierre Cardin, Pierre Junod, Pierre Petit, PIRELLI, Pittman Outdoors, Playmobil, Plum, Plusbuyer, Polar, Polaroid, Police, Porsamo Bleu, Porsche Design, Posma, PowerAll, Powers Fasteners, Precious Kids, Premium Connection, Primo Products, Project D London, Projects Watches, Projekt, Proman Products, Promaster, Pulsar, Puma, Pure Energy, Purtest, Pyle, PYLE AUDIO, Q And Q, Qingdao Shenghuajie Machinery Co. LTD, Radiant Watches, Rado, Rasta Imposta, Ray Ban, Raymond Weil, RAZER, RCA, Reactor, Red Line, Reebok, Reed, Reign Watches, Relic, Relic By Fossil, Resultco, Revue Thommen, Rhino By Marc Ecko, Richard & Co, Rico Inc, Rico Industries, Rinovati, Rip Curl, Ritmo Mundo, River Woods, Riverberry, Riverstone Industries, Roberto Bianci, Roberto Cavalli, Rocawear, Rockwell, Rockwell Publishing, Rodenstein, Rolex, Ronstan, Rosendahl, Rotary, Rothco, Rousseau Company, Royce Leather, RSW, Rts Companies Us Inc, Rumba Time, Safco Products, Saint Honore, Salvador Kitti, Salvatore Ferragamo, SAMSUNG, Sandoz Watches, Sangean, SAS Safety, Screen Gems, Scuderia Ferrari, SDI TECHNOLOGIES, Sea Eagle, Seahope, SEAPRO, Sector, Seiko, Sentry, Sentry Industries, Senze Electronics Co. Ltd, Seven Star, Seventh Generation, SHARK ARMY WATCHES, SHARK WATCH, Sharp, SHENHUA, Shenzhen Bodo Watch Industry Co. Ltd, Shenzhen Huge Industry Limited, Shenzhen Jieyong Starking Clocks & Watch, Shenzhen Luckystar Electrical CoLtd, Shenzhen Oband Technology Co. Ltd., Shenzhen Roman Technology Co. Ltd, Shenzhen Shanhai Technology Ltd., Shenzhen ShunXinDa Trading Co.Ltd, Shenzhen Tianxunda Technology Co.Ltd, Shenzhen Xinjiaguangdian Ltd., Sheryl Otoole, SHHORS WATCH, SHIBA ELECTRONICS FTY, Shield, Shield Watches, Shine Company Inc., Shine Future Co. LTD, Shop-Vac, Sichiray, SIGHTHOLDERDIAMONDS, SIGMA, Sigma Sport, Silvana K Designs, Simon Chang, Simplify Watches, Sinobi Watches, Skagen, Skmei Watch Co. Ltd, Skyfire, Skylink Technologies, Skytimer, Smith & Wesson, SMKJ, SODIAL, Soleus International, Sonic, Sonic Alert, Sonnet Technologies, Sony Bmg Music Entertainment, SONYA PRODUCTS, Sophie And Freda, Soyuz, Spazio24, SPECIAL PROJECTS, Speedo, Sperry Instruments, Sperry Top Sider, Sprout, Srad Tech, St. Moritz Watch Corp., Star Wars, Steinhausen, Storm, Storm Accessories, Strawberry Shortcake, Stuhrling Original, Style Craft, SUN SEED COMPANY, Suntime, Super Techno, Superdry, SuperJeweler, Supremefactory, SURFACE, Suunto, Swarovski, Swatch, Swift Green, SwimWays, SWISS, Swiss Army, Swiss Eagle, SWISS LEGEND, Swiss Master, Swiss Military, Swiss Precimax, Swiss Watch International, Syllable, Synnex, T-Mobile, Tag Heuer, TAIGU WATCHES SHOPPING MALL, Taylor Cole, Tech, Techno, Techno Com, Techno Com By Kc, Techno Master, Techno Royale, TechnoMarine, Ted Baker, Ted Lapidus, Tendence, Tense Watches, Tense Wood, Tense Wood Watches, The Bling Factory, The House Of Marley LLC., Thirsty Watch, Thomas Sabo, Tic Fashion Watches, Timberland, Time-it, Time100-watch, Timebear, Timeforce, Timeless, TIMEX, TinkSky, Tissot, Titanium, TKO Orlogi, TOKYObay, Tom Ford, Tommy Bahama, Tommy Hilfiger, TOMOTOP, TomTom, TOMTOP, TopBox, Torgoen, Tous, Toy Box, Toy Watch, Toys R Us, Toywatch, Trademark Global Inc., Transcend, Traser, Trimax Sports, TRIUMPH, Triumph Motorcycles, TRIWA, TRIXES, Troika, Trudi, TRUE, Tsovet, Tudor Publishers Incorporated, TVG, TW Steel, U-Boat, U-Style, U.S. Polo, U.S.Agency, UKM Gifts, ULTRAK, Ulysse Nardin, Umbra, Unemployed Philosophers Guild, Union Products, Unionlever International Group, Unique's Shop, Unique-Bargains, Unlisted, Unlisted By Kenneth Cole, Urban Station (usa) Inc., UZI, V8, Valentino, VALEO, Vanceur, Vandue Corporation, Vangoddy, Vecceli, Vention Technology Limited, Versace, Versus, Versus By Versace, Vestal, Viceroy, Victorinox, Victorio I Lucchino, Vince Camuto, Visage, Visol, VistaBella, Vistan LLC, VLC Dist, Void Watches, Von Dutch Watches, Vtech, Vuarnet, Watx&Colors, WEIDE WATCH, WEIQIN WATCH, Welder Watches, WENGER, West Group, Westbrass, Westchester, WESTCLOX, WeWOOD, Whimsical Gifts, Wilson Sporting Goods Co., WINNER, Winnerbiao, Wittnauer, World Of Watches, X GAMES, Xbniao Marketplace, Xcsource, Xezo, Xiaomi Tech, XLNC Watch, XOXO, Xtreme, Yelang Watch, Yiamiacase, YIBEI Toy Companies, YiShui, YKS, Yong Hao Electric Power Co. LTD, YOUNGSTOWN GLOVE CO., YourBestChoice, Zan Headgear, Zenith Watches, Zeno, Zeon, Ziiiro, Zippo, Zodaca, Zodiac, Zoppini
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is thrown by the leading number. A simple work-around is to use a single quote mark. In the target cell start by typing `'`. Then, while still in edit mode, paste in the rest immediately after the single quote. That makes sure that Excel treats it as a string.

If you skip this and just enter the original string into a cell formatted as text, it actually seems to work even though it gives the error message you mentioned. It seems that the error message pop-up is itself the error, but the cell value itself is the desired string. This seems to be a an outright bug in Excel.

Comment: I was having this problem for hours, so glad yo posted the correct solution.

Thank you so much.